# Find the power of a number

Tags: java, functional-programming

My program asks users to enter a number which is a power of 2 (1,2,4,8..128). Further, I have to replace `a[number]` to true or false. Currently, I am using a switch statement to do that. However, I intend to write a function which will calculate the power. How can we optimize this code:

```
switch (requested) {
    case 1:
        if (b[1] == true)
            b[1] = false;
        break;
    case 2:
        if (b[2] == true)
            b[2] = false;
        break;
    case 4:
        if (b[3] == true)
            b[3] = false;
        break;
    case 16:
        if (b[4] == true)
            b[4] = false;
        break;
    case 32:
        if (b[5] == true)
            b[5] = false;
        break;
    case 64:
        if (b[6] == true)
            b[6] = false;
        break;
    case 128:
        if (b[7] == true)
            b[7] = false;
        break;
}
```

Comment: `if (true) then false` makes no sense. Just set it straight to false. If it's already false, then it won't matter that it's being set to false

Comment: How about https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog

Comment: What happened to `case 8` btw?

Comment: btw 1 == 2^^0 and 2 == 2^^1

Comment: You don't need to check a boolean is true before setting it to false.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function provided in `Integer`:

```
int idx = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(requested); 
b[idx] = false;
```

I would also consider validating the user input to make sure it is in fact a power of two:

```
int idx = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(requested); 
if ((1<<idx) != requested) {
  throw new InvalidInputException(...);
}
b[idx+1] = false;
```

Comment: To start at `b[1]` as in the question, wouldn’t you need to do `b[idx + 1]`? May also want to check the index is within array size, Nice solution.

Comment: Warning there is a typo, it is `numberOfTrailingZeros`

Comment: Thanks Ole and Nicolas, edited to fix indicated issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why your array index starts at 1, but I will answer based on that anyway.

You could count the number of bitshifts required until 0. That would give you the correct index:

```
int index = 0; // If you want 0-based index, start this at -1.
while(requested > 0) {
    index++;
    requested >>= 1;
}
b[index] = false;
```

[Here is a working example](http://ideone.com/vofPpo)

---

**Warning**: This will alter the value of `requested`, if you need that to remain the original value for any reason, then create a copy of it: `int copy = requested;` and use that instead.

**Note**: I expect there is probably a more appropriate function built-in, but I don't know what it is off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use map if you are matching numbers to booleans ?
Then you could simply check and change the value whenever the user hits the adequate number.

```
    //requested by user
    long requested = 16;

    //I create simply a map of powers set to true initially.
    //I presume you have something similar
    Map<Long, Boolean> powerBoolMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    long power = 1;
    int numberOfPowersToStore = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPowersToStore; i++) {
        power = power * 2;
        powerBoolMap.put(power, true);
    }

    //Then here you can just check the requested number against any 
    //key which is your 'power' and invert it or set to whatever you want.
    for (Map.Entry<Long, Boolean> e : powerBoolMap.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getKey() == requested) {
            powerBoolMap.replace(requested, !e.getValue());
        }
    }
```

and the output is

```
{2=true, 4=true, 8=true, 16=false, 32=true, 64=true, 128=true, 256=true, 512=true, 1024=true, 2048=true ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear what you are heading at. You are saying something about “calculate the power”, but the input is supposed to be already a power (of two). You also say you “have to replace `a[number]` to true or false” without any explanation why you (think you) have to. And that `number` is supposed to be correlated with the exponent of the power of two can only be guessed from the code.

Further, you have tagged you question with “functional-programming”, though there is no sign of FP in your question at all.

Assuming that this is a convoluted attempt to dissect a number into its power of two components, to be represented as boolean values (equivalent to the bit set in the number’s binary representation), you can do a similar thing using `BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { requested })`. The bitset is already semantically equivalent to an array of `boolean` values and when constructed as above, it has already the right bits set to `true`.

You can also pretty-print it:

```
int requested = 100;
System.out.println(requested+" = "+
    BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { requested }).stream()
          .mapToObj(i -> "2^"+i).collect(Collectors.joining(" + ")));
```

will print

```
100 = 2^2 + 2^5 + 2^6
```